# Change standard label prefix for Crosstabs in SPSS Output

Tags: spss

When I run a crosstab in SPSS with columns and or row percentages the standard labeling for the percentages is `% within <VARLABEL>` (or `% innerhalb von <VARLABEL>` when german output is used). In some cases I find this to long and I would like to define a shorter version of this prefix within the syntax (So I don't have to change everything manualy). How, if possible, can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jignesh, NO!  The text files that define the labels for output are compiled files and should not be messed with.

One way to change the labeling would be to write an autoscript in Python or Basic that would modify the labels.  You attach this to the table type via Edit > Options > Scripts, and it is run every time a table of that type is created.

That requires, of course, the ability to write such a script.  Another simpler way to do this would be to use the `SPSSINC MODIFY TABLES` extension command with a very small Python code fragment.  You would have to run this command explicitly, but it could iterate through all the Viewer tables of the specified type and make the changes.  Here is an example with `CROSSTABS`.  In this example, the custom function changes any row labels that start with "% within" to just "%".

```
CROSSTABS  
  /TABLES=jobcat BY gender  
  /CELLS=COUNT ROW.

begin program.  
def relabel(obj, i, j, numrows, numcols, section, more,custom):  
    oldlabel = obj.GetValueAt(i, j)  
    newlabel = oldlabel.replace("% within", "%")  
    obj.SetValueAt(i, j, newlabel)  
end program.


SPSSINC MODIFY TABLES subtype="'Crosstabulation'"
SELECT="^% within "
REGEXP=YES DIMENSION= ROWS
LEVEL = -1  PROCESS = PRECEDING 
/STYLES  APPLYTO=LABELS customfunction="\__main__.relabel".
```

In order to use the inline definition of the function, you need at least version 1.5.0 of `SPSSINC MODIFY TABLES`.  If you have an older version installed and don't want to update it, the Python function would just need to be saved in a separate Python file.

In Statistics version 22 or later you can download and install extension commands such as `MODIFY TABLES` from the Utilities menu.

Comment: I typically always use `SPSSINC MODIFY TABLES` for `CTABLES` that I completely forgot it could be used for all/any tables. Yes, of course much better approach than hacking system files...(not that I have ever done that...)

Comment: Works great after I deleted the backslash in  `"\__main__.relabel"`  -> `"__main__.relabel"` Otherwise I would get an error.

Comment: @JKP Thanks a lot for developing the Modify Tables extension. In my current job it often saves my life(time) :-)

Comment: @JKP is there a way to regexp this search? It works, but it's replacing '% within' with '%' and I'd like to search for everything after the '% within' as well.  For example, '% within Q1' replaced fully with just '%'.

Answer (score 0):

[`CUSTOM TABLES`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_ctables.htm?lang=en) is designed to offer much flexibility to apply these types of customizations as you wish. I wouldn’t know how you change this default text in `CROSSTABS` however. I suspect you could hack some of the system files, to achieve this, if you really wanted to do this.